String aggregation in SQL Server
I have a table as below :



COMMENT_ID
ID
USER_COMMENTS




1521013*1521167-1
1521013*1521167
This is to inform


1521013*1521167-3
1521013*1521167
asking for


1521013*1521167-4
1521013*1521167
detailed report.


1521013*1521167-2
1521013*1521167
that user is



Need to aggregate the user_comments based on comment_id
Desired OP:



ID
COMMENT




1521013*1521167
This is to inform that user is asking for detailed report.



I tried below :
 SELECT ID,STRING_AGG(USER_COMMENTS,' ') comment from table_A group by ID;

it gives me :



ID
comment




1521013*1521167
This is to inform asking for detailed report. that user is



The comments are not in order by comment_id
DDLs are as below:
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A
(
  COMMENT_ID VARCHAR(100),
  ID VARCHAR(100),
  USER_COMMENTS VARCHAR(100)
  );
  
  INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('1521013*1521167-1','1521013*1521167','This is to inform');
  INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('1521013*1521167-3','1521013*1521167','asking for ');
  INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('1521013*1521167-4','1521013*1521167','detailed report.');
  INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('1521013*1521167-2','1521013*1521167','that user is ');

How do I aggregate it based on comment_id order ?
Any inputs are appreciated.
Thanks

will include version next time. Thanks

@Novice_Techie, thanks for understanding.

Please try
SELECT ID,STRING_AGG(USER_COMMENTS,' ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COMMENT_ID ASC) AS comment 
FROM table_A 
GROUP BY ID


I am able to get what I need as of now, it's working.
wasn't aware of "within group" .  Thanks, will look into it in detail.
